# Counting number of column with non-blank cells above

Tags: excel

I have a sheet where each row is a time and each column is a subject and each entry is a payment.  For every time, I want to count the number of subjects that have ever received a payment (i.e. how many subjects have non-blank columns above that row).  How can I do this in a single column?

Thanks for any help!

(Having trouble copying from excel.  First four columns are data; fifth column is my intended result. # = number, - = blank, | = column separator. Thanks to Siddharth Rout for formatting help)

```
# | - | - | # || 2

- | # | - | # || 3

# | # | - | - || 3

- | - | - | - || 3

- | - | # | - || 4
```

Comment: Please explain further.  Can you paste one row?

Comment: please paste sample row

Comment: So it's easy to count the number of blank columns in a single row, I want to count the number of columns where the entry for that row is blank and _every cell above is also blank_. So the first four columns are my data and the fifth column is what I want.

Comment: 1 -- -- 1 2
-- 3 -- 2 3 
2 4 -- -- 3 
-- -- -- -- 3
 3 5 6 7 4

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually really liked this question.

The only way I could think of doing it was by adding in an extra "helper" row at the top of the sheet.

Here how I would do this:

- Add in a new row at the top of your worksheet (Row 1)
- In cell A1 (newly inserted row), put in the following formula:

  `=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((A2:A9000<>""),0),0)+1`

(This will tell you the first row in that column where a value exists - Change the `A9000` to a more suitable number of rows for your data):

- Drag that formula across all the columns for which you have data
- In the column you want your final result (Supposing it is column E for this example), put in the following formula in `E2`:

  `=COUNTIF($A$1:$D$1,"<="&ROW())`
- Drag that formula down that entire column and you should have your desired result.

---

As an explanation, the helper row finds the first row that has data in it in your table and the final column simply counts all the values in that helper row that have a number less than or equal to the current row number.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Perfect! For future reference, the +1 in the MATCH formula is ROW(first entry of data)-1. So if your data starts on row 3 it would be +2.